# Create link in pdf with tcpdf

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

How can I create a link with TCPDF?

When using the `writeHTML()` function and passing my whole html content, TCPDF doesn't make my links clickable. They are blue and underlined but I cannot click them.

Here is what I did.

```
$html = "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a>";
$tcpdf = new TCPDF();
$tcpdf->writeHTML($html);
$tcpdf-Output('output.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Not really answering the question, but have you experimented with **dompdf** (http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)? I've played with it a bit in the past, and haven't experienced any such issues...

Comment: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps here is an example of how to parse HTML content in tcpdf. First link on google using your question title.

Comment: Are you converting html code?? You should be doing something wrong because it works perfectly to me. Maybe you could write down more of your code

Comment: I know this is closed/old, but I was also curious if this could be done using html.  It works for me.  Probably should add the http:// or whatever protocol.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a6669ae88090963e9487d0388c7577dc9), you can use the `Write()` method on your TCPDF object to achieve this. For example:

```
$tcpdf->Write(10, 'Google', 'http://www.google.com/', false, 'L', true);
```

Would write a line with the text Google (left-aligned and with a line break, just added for a better example).

Comment: I was wrong in my explanation. Infact, my function parse my entire text before to give it to my tcpdf object, so at this moment, i check if a link is present (with a regex) and i replace it. Or rather, i try.
So i can't use the tcpdf functions.

Comment: @Naelyth Well, you didn't say that. But you can't make TCPDF "automagically" detect links in your document, you need to use the proper functions for this to work.

Comment: Problem solved. Never let the student make the code...

Comment: @Oldskool thanks!, for me it was a more situable solution than using writeHTMLCell() method ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe tcpdf has a problem with single quotes vs double quotes.

You wrote:

```
$html = "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a>";
```

I think if you did it this way it would work:

```
$html = '<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution suggested by Some Guy and it worked for me. Using:

```
$html = '<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>';
```

Instead of:

```
$html = "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a>";
```

Comment: Hi,  this is most likely a comment, not an answer. Take a look here: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for better understanding our rules