# How can I add link on pdf with TCPDF using cell method?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to create an external link on pdf file generated by [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) library using Cell method. I've written code something like this:

```
$this->pdf = new PDF();
$this->pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Click here', 1, 0, 'L', true, 'https://example.com', 1, false, 'T', 'C');
```

The above code simply print the text and doesn't create a link however, if I include the link along with text on the third argument as below then only it creates a link:

```
$this->pdf = new PDF();
$this->pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Click here https://example.com', 1, 0, 'L', true, 'https://example.com', 1, false, 'T', 'C');
```

I've also tried the accepted solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849454/create-link-in-pdf-with-tcpdf) thread but it didn't work for me either.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Working code

I cannot reproduce the issue with using `tcpdf` 6.4.4:

#### composer.json

```json
{
    "require": {
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.4"
    }
}
```

#### test.php

```php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->AddPage();

//Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=0, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M')
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Click here', 1, 0, 'L', false, 'https://example.com', 1, false, 'T', 'C');
$pdf->Output('example_004.pdf', 'I');
```

### Output

[image]

Can you tell me which version of the library you are using?

Comment: I'm using version "6.2.12". I've upgraded to the version that you specified but also it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: if you create a new project with my code, does my code work for you? If so, could you create a temporary github repo that shows the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Douma It worked on a new project. It looks like there's an error on my existing code. Cheers!